# What kind of directories are these?

Tags: mount, directory, symbolic-link, hard-link

I'm looking at a directory that was created for backups. One of the subfolders is the root of a Git repo, and contains the .git folder. That folder also contains links to other folders in the system. The idea was that `git add/commit/push` would essentially backup selected changes across the environment with full version control.

But I can't figure out what kind of folder structure this is. This Ubuntu v20.04 kernel prevents hardlinks to directories. The folders are just names, not "name -> actual/folder/name". These folders look like any other, when viewed with common ls and lsattr commands. I'm not sure if these folders are mounted, FUSE, or symbolic links that appear like any inode-attached directory.

Can someone provide some commands to identify these folders? I've seen suggestions for using 'find' but without knowing what I'm looking for, I would randomly be trying different find options. I'm hoping for something much more straightforward.

My intent is to understand and use what's there, or to re-configure to something more recognizable. Until I get a handle on it, I certainly don't want to just `rm` the subfolder pointers, because I have no idea what might happen.

Thanks.

EDIT1, results of testing :

1. `ln` shows same inode, filename doesn't distinguish apparent hardlink to directory.

   ```
   # ls -aliF /var/local/repo/configs | grep etc  
   43 drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 12288 Jun 8 06:58 etc/  
   # ls -aliF / | grep etc  
   43 drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 12288 Jun 8 06:58 etc/
   ```
2. Not identified with 'find'

   ```
   find /var/local/repo/configs -xtype l
   ```
3. Try 'namei' on both folders:

   ```
   # namei /var/local/repo/configs/etc  
    f: /var/local/repo/configs/etc  
       d /  
       d var  
       d local  
       d repo  
       d configs  
       d etc  
   # namei /etc  
    f: /etc  
       d /  
       d etc
   ```
4. `readlink -f` just echoes the folder,

   ```
   /var/local/repo/configs  
   /var/local/repo/configs/etc  
   /var/local/repo/configs/etc/rspamd
   ```
5. `file` command says /var/local/repo/configs/etc is a directory
6. `stat` command shows exactly the same data for repo path and /etc, except of course that the File field for each shows the queried location ... they do not both show /etc.

Checks on other files also indicate they are real folders and not links.

Comment: Try with `namei -lx` instead of just `namei`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit above and the question here. There is no difference in the long format. The only mount point is / root. The 'etc' folder does not show as a mount point when viewed as /etc, nor from the repo path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what this is. At boot the following script is executed to do a "bind mount".

```
#!/bin/env bash

BASE=/var/local/repositories/network/$HOSTNAME

do_mount() {
  # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount/198591#198591
  mkdir -p "$BASE$1"
  mount --bind $1 "$BASE$1"
}

do_mount /var/local/real/folder
do_mount /etc
...
```

In that **awesome** [what-is-a-bind-mount post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount/198591#198591), there is this:

> Recent kernels do track bind mounts and expose the information through <code/proc/PID/mountinfo, which allows findmnt to indicate bind mount as such.

That is a link to [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295525/how-is-findmnt-able-to-list-bind-mounts) where this wisdom is found:

> If you look at /proc/self/mountinfo you'll see the kernel view of the mount world for this process...

OK, so on my system:

```
# grep etc /proc/self/mountinfo
2568 32 252:1 /etc /var/local/repositories/network/zzz/etc rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/vda1 rw
```

And **that** is the answer to "what kind of directories are these?" They are bind mounts. And mountinfo tells us the relationships of sources and targets.

And I need to improve our system docs so details about customizations like this don't get lost.